# How do I get sharepoint list items by passing ID as the parameter dynamically using rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

I have to fetch values for particular Id's by passing ID in URL.

Ex: if I write `?ID=2`, it should give me the values corresponding to the id in the list.

Comment: Where are you using the REST api? Please provide more context about the issue you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the below endpoint in REST API to get the list items:

```
<site url>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/items(<item id>)
```

**Example:**

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test List')/items(2)
```

If you want to fetch the item ID from URL query string parameter then check my answer given in below post:

[How to pass SiteURL as a parameter into a Form to insert via API Post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277201/how-to-pass-siteurl-as-a-parameter-into-a-form-to-insert-via-api-post/277219#277219)

**Additional References**:

1. [Working with list items by using REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#working-with-list-items-by-using-rest).
2. [CRUD Operation On List Items Using REST API Services In SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-on-list-items-using-rest-api-services-in-shar/)

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I have been trying this but it does not work. Adding 2 as the end point would hardcode it, i want it to be dynamic as in when i write ?ID=1 in URL, it should give me the data corresponding to it

Comment: Then you need to get the item ID from URL, save it in variable and then use it in REST endpoint. Check the links I provided it should clarify all the things.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the format `?ID=2`, you may have a try below syntax:

```
https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4xxx9')/Items(@ID)?@ID=2
```

BR

Comment: Hi, Thanks, can you also suggest what can be done if i need to pass id other than 2 in the url? like id=3 and so on?

Comment: If the query item id is 3, just change the value from 2 to 3. "....4xxx9')/Items(@ID)?@ID=3"